# JQuery file upload not detecting dynamically added inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a form, in this form you can either 1 or several added Users, each user must upload a file img.

I have jquery.fileupload library, and it works fine for the first input, but if the user needs to add more fields to add more users, then those dynamically added input fields are not detected by the fileupload jquery code.

HTML code for where the fields go:

```
<div class="input text input-nb">

    <!-- DIV where the input fields are adden from jquery -->
    <div id="bloque_integrante_wrap">
    </div>

    <!-- DIV that contains the link to add more input fields -->
    <div id="agregar_mas_wrap">
        <a id="agregar-mas-integrantes-nb" href="javascript:void(0)"><img id="agregar-mas-nb-img" src="../img/agregar-mas.jpg" /> <label id="agregar-mas-nb-2">agregar mas</label></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js/jquery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var index = 1;

    var bloque = '<div class="bloque_integrante">'+
                '<div class="inner_wrap_nb" id="bloque_integrante_'+index+'">'+
                    '<label>Nombre </label><input class="nombre_integrante_nb" name="data[nombre_integrante_'+index+']" type="text" />'+
                    '<label>Rol </label><input class="rol_integrante_nb" name="data[rol_integrante_'+index+']" type="text" />'+
                    '<a class="bonito-button subir-ci-nb fileinput-button">Subir Copia C.I.'+
                    ' <input type="file" name="data[ci_integrante_'+index+']" id="ci_integrante_'+index+'" class="ci_integrante_nb" >  </a>'+
                    '<a class="eliminar-integrante-nb" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>'+
                    '<img class="nb-ci-prev-status" id="preview_nb_'+index+'" src="../img/check-nb.png">'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';

   // Adding the default first block, must always have 1 input at start
   $("#bloque_integrante_wrap").append(bloque);

  // The listener to when user clicks to add more fields
  $("#agregar-mas-integrantes-nb").on("click",function(){

   index = index + 1;

    var bloque2 = '<div class="bloque_integrante">'+
                '<div class="inner_wrap_nb" id="bloque_integrante_'+index+'">'+
                    '<label>Nombre </label><input class="nombre_integrante_nb" name="data[nombre_integrante_'+index+']" type="text" />'+
                    '<label>Rol </label><input class="rol_integrante_nb" name="data[rol_integrante_'+index+']" type="text" />'+
                    '<a class="bonito-button subir-ci-nb fileinput-button">Subir Copia C.I.'+
                    ' <input type="file" name="data[ci_integrante_'+index+']" id="ci_integrante_'+index+'" class="ci_integrante_nb" >  </a>'+
                    '<a class="eliminar-integrante-nb" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>'+
                    '<img class="nb-ci-prev-status" id="preview_nb_'+index+'" src="../img/check-nb.png">'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';

      $("#bloque_integrante_wrap").append(bloque2);
   });



   // This is where i process when file input is changed (user choses file)
   // This only works for the first input, added as soon as document loads
   $("#subir-imagen-banda-nb").on("change", function(){

         readURL(this,"#foto-nb-icon",30,30);
   });


});
```

The function readURL adds the URL of the uploaded file to a DOM element, usually the thumb icon showing the uploaded file.

This is only working for the first element I add after document loads.

Comment: It seems like you may need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: @dave thanks, that actually did the trick. Tbh, i tried it before but I was using a div that was also dinamycally added as a selector for the delegation. I now used a div that is always there (#bloque_integrante_wrap) and instantly worked!

Answer (score 1):

As @dave pointed out, I should use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to detect my dynamically added elements.

So to detect this, my Jquery listener looks like this:

```
   $("#bloque_integrante_wrap").on("change",".ci_integrante_nb",function(){

       var contenedor1 = $(this).attr("id");
       var tmp = contenedor1.split("_");
       var num = tmp[2];

       readURL(this,"#preview_nb_"+num,30,30,"feedback");
   });
```

Notice how I use `#bloque_integrante_wrap` div selector, which is where my dynamic elements are added, and `.ci_integrante_nb` is the class that every dynamic element has.